# TargetNullValue = '' not working WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have the following textbox , not sure why the formatting won't go to normal but you get the point.

```
<TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="InputVolts" 
                 TargetNullValue='' 
                 FallbackValue=''>
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <u:NonEmptyStringValidator/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This textbox is bound to the following property:

```
public int? InputVolts
{
     get { return _InputVolts; }
     set { Set(ref _InputVolts, value);}
}
```

In my form, if I type a number like 240 into the textbox the view model will update with that value. If I try and delete the 240 from the textbox, the view model does not update the InputVolts property accordingly.

I am aware of the TargetNullValue solution from the following  [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579731/value-of-the-property-does-not-change-when-the-textbox-is-cleared)

**EDIT:**
Okay I found the problem, my NonEmptyStringValidator is causing this issue. I want to still have this validation rule on my text box though. Is there anyway to adjust this to still keep the validation rule but make the textbox return back to null when deleted?

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty.");
        if (value != null)
        {
            string valueAsString = value as string;
            if (valueAsString.Length > 0)
                validationResult = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
        return validationResult;
    }
```

I also tried using the FallBackValue and nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: @mjwills sorry to early in the morning for me. I fixed the title lol

Comment: change `''` to `""`

Comment: I have tried that already to. Did not work for me.

Comment: is the InputVolts defined as described? without the help of an INotifyPropertyChanged or DP?

Comment: what does `Set` function do?

Comment: Its does all the notify property change events and all that. I am using mvvm light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<u:NonEmptyStringValidator/>` might prevent the update to an empty string.